# How to match PFObjects, get a count, and display objects in descending order using Parse and Swift?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, count, match

I know its alot.  If you can help with sections please do.  I'm building a video ranking app and saving video data in Parse using unique YouTube VideoId's.  I want to match up the id's getting a count of each and display each in descending order.  Basically a Top 20 App.  My video info is being saved like this.....

```
let videoSave = PFObject(className: "UserVideos")
        videoSave.setObject(self.videoARY, forKey: "vid\(self.saveValueLBL.text!)")
        videoSave["userObjectId"] = PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId
        videoSave["username"] = PFUser.currentUser()!.username
        videoSave["ytID"] = self.videoId
        videoSave.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error ) -> Void in
            if success == true
            {
                if videoSave["username"] == nil
                {
                    videoSave["username"] = PFUser.currentUser()!.username
                    videoSave.saveInBackground()
                }
            }
        }
```

And I'm getting them back like this.....

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "UserVideos")
query.whereKeyExists("vid1")
query.orderByDescending("ytID")
query.limit = 20
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (topVids , error ) -> Void in
    if !(error != nil)
    {
        print(topVids!)
    }
}
```

*** UPDATE ***

I've found somethings online that suggests I'm doing it right; that I just need to match the unique strings together and order descending utilizing "for loops" e.g.  If you have any ideas about this please let me know?

Please help.  Thankx